# Can't access 127.0.0.1 or any other ip, localhost works

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, windows-7

I'm using Nodejs & Expressjs.

When i try to access my app through http://www.localhost:3000/ the app loads just fine. but if i try any other loopback IP (127.0.0.1 / my PC name / my PC IP) i get :

> Request URL:http://127.0.0.1:3000/ Request Method:GET Status Code:301
>   Moved Permanently

And then :

> GET http://www.127.0.0.1:3000/ net::ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED

I'm using windows 7.

What I've tried after a lot of web searching:

1. Editing hosts file, adding :

   127.0.0.1       localhost

   ::1             localhost
2. Disable windows firewall
3. Explicity tell express to listen all IPs : (with or without '0.0.0.0')

   ```
   app.listen(3000, "0.0.0.0", function() {
     console.log("listen on 3000"); 
   });
   ```
4. Different ports (8080, 8081, etc..)
5. with http:// without or any other variation.

In addition if i run Wamp server for it's instance(e.g accessing phpmyadmin), everything works great. (localhost, 127.0.0.1 etc over port 80)

Comment: why www in front of 127.0.0.1 ? you do not need it

Comment: www is definitly false try ``http://127.0.0.1:3000`` and it will work without spaces. if not check if cross site requests are allowed

Comment: chrome adds automatically probably, i tried to access http:// 127.0.0.1:3000

Comment: @mtizziani ofcourse without spaces. and i run chrome with permission for cross origin (otherwise localhost would not work as well)

Comment: I've edited my question and corrected the flow i get, found the issue, tnx !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that I've added redirect from none www to www with the following lines :

```
// non-www to www redirect
app.get('/*', function (req, res, next) {
    if (req.headers.host.match(/^www/) === null) {
        res.redirect(301, 'http://www.' + req.headers.host + req.url);
    } else {
        next();
    }
});
```

And it affected 127.0.0.1 as well, removing it for development fixed the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing localhost by 0.0.0.0

Answer (score 0):

Remove www from the ip adress and it should work.

Comment: I've edited my question, chrome added the www automatically (probably because it could access without it) but i tried to access without it.